# How can i invoke my python method

Tags: python, class, methods

pretty new to Python - OO - have been using the procedural python for some time. I wrote a silly class and method out and am having trouble invoking my method:

```
class Jpd:
    #attributes share data among class objects.
    my_age = 26

    def __init__(self, value):
        #method-level attribute data.
        self.my_age = value

    def ageToRetireFrom(self ):
        print self.my_age + 20

    def ageToBuyHome(self):
        print self.my_age + 5

retire = Jpd.ageToRetireFrom()
home = Jpd.ageToBuyHome()
```

If I try calling my file `example.py` like:

```
>>> import example
>>> j = example.Jpd()
```

I get:

```
NameError: global name 'value' is not defined
```

I know this is complaining that my `value` attribute isn't assigned. Can someone help me invoke this method?

Thank you

Comment: Where are you expecting `value` to be defined?

Comment: I updated my code. It wasnt in the __init__ , but it still isnt working.

Comment: Your code doesn't match the traceback - if `value` was an `__init__` parameter, you'd be told you weren't passing it...

Comment: You'd have to pass `value` to the `__init__` function: `j = example.Jpd(30)`

Comment: Your posted code neither defines nor calls `value`. The error isn't in your posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the `__init__` method, that *becomes* the call signature when you want to create a new instance.  So from your example, you'd use:

```
j = example.Jpd(15)
```

To make a new Person who was 15 years old.

Comment: Good call. I fixed this on my end and its working, how can I make the return not be the memory address that looks like: <example.Jpd instance at 0x10c1f5e18>

Comment: @CodeTalk that's a separate question, but that's defined in the `__str__` or `__repr__` methods.

Comment: @CodeTalk - Look into the `__str__`, `__repr__`, and `__unicode__` methods.  But yes, that should be another question, or you should probably read more of a beginners' guide to Python Classes.

Comment: @AdamSmith - thanks for letting me know, will do some homework on it. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

when you create an instance of your class `Jpd`, should be this way:

```
j = example.Jpd(20)
```

since you defined your `__init__(self, value)`, so you need to pass a value when creating an instance of your class